# Ubuntu. Boost. Coroutine. Undefined reference to `..._fcontext`

Tags: c++, boost

Пытаюсь прикрутить к программе корутины boost-овские, однако этой строки, программа перестала собираться - падало с кучей `undefined reference to`:

```
boost::asio::spawn(socket->get_io_service(), boost::bind(&Connection::work, shared_from_this(), _1));
```

Затем, я добавил флаг линковщику `-lboost_coroutine`, количество ошибок уменьшилось, но все равно остались две:

```
(.text+0x14d)| |undefined reference to 'make_fcontext'|
(.text+0x290)| |undefined reference to 'jump_fcontext'|
```

Что еще нужно прилинковать? (гугл как-то не очень помог)

Флаги компиляции сейчас: `-pthread -lboost_system -lboost_coroutine`

ОС: `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS на VirtualBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением еще флага `-lboost_context`

Comment: Отметь свой ответ решением.

Comment: Завтра отмечу, пока не дает